# Return Type of an async method

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, c#-4.0

I have an async method in C# as follows:

```
public async Task<string> GetData(int id)
{
    Task<string> inp =  CommonMethod(id);
    return inp;
}

public async Task<string> CommonMethod(int id)
{
    string output;
    output = await service.GetSomeDummyData(id);
    return output;
}
```

I am getting an error message

> Since this is an async method,the return expression must be of type string rather than `Task<string>`.

SO, I converted the return type as :

```
public async Task<string> GetData(int id)
{
    Task<string> inp =  CommonMethod(id);
    return inp.ToString();
}
```

The code is getting complied successfully .

I am new to asynchronous programming, is the above conversion method is a best practice of returning **string**? Because from the **CommonMethod**,
I am collecting the return type in `Task<string>` , and in the next statement I am using `inp.Tostring()`. Little bit of Dilemma in using the correct return types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should rather do it this way:

```
public async Task<string> GetData(int id)
{
    string inp = await CommonMethod(id);
    return inp;
}
```

The same way you do it in your second call.
The returned value will get wrapped up in a Task automatically.

Because you had Task as your return type, and you had packed this in Task manually in your code, it was throwing an error there.

Comment: exactly! or even `return await CommonMethod(id);`

Answer (score 6):

When you add the `async` modifier to the method, you're telling the compiler to automatically wrap its return value as a Task. Or a sequence of Tasks that continue each other on each `await` statement, loosely speaking. So your code:

```
public async Task<string> GetData(int id)
{
    Task<string> inp =  CommonMethod(id);
    return inp;
}
```

would compile to something *resembling*:

```
public Task<string> GetData(int id)
{
     return Task.Run() => 
     {
         Task<string> inp =  CommonMethod(id);
         return inp; 
     }
}
```

So what you're returning there isn't a `Task<string>`, but a `Task<Task<string>>` - a Task which returns another Task (which then returns  string), which doesn't match the method signature.

So what you want to do is either drop the `async` modifier and return the internal task directly:

```
public Task<string> GetData(int id)
{
    Task<string> inp =  CommonMethod(id);
    return inp;
}
```

which will work, and return the internal `CommonMethod` task, or add an internal `await` statement to return a new Task over the results of the internal task:

```
public async Task<string> GetData(int id)
{
    string inp =  await CommonMethod(id);
    return inp;
}
```

which, again loosely, returns a task *immediately* when the await statement is reached, with the code after it (the `return` statement) in a `ContinueWith` block over the internal task. When the internal task completes, the code after `await` runs, and returns the result as the Result of the original Task that was returned earlier.